# Provisional certificate after transferring the app

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I just sold and transferred my app to the buyer. He wants to update the app with his ads, so my question is does he need to make his own provisional profile(certificate) for this app, or just to type the old bundle I’d and that’s it? He just registered his Apple developer account and he doesn’t have any profile created yet. I only know how to upload the app to the AppStore, but I am not sure what is the next step, how he can update and upload new version of app to the AppStore from his profile? I hope you understand what I ask, my English is not that good. Thanks for the help. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Since the developer account will be changed , then the bundle id should too ,  and any associated api keys & ads configurations with it , then he should create the certificates and profiles

Comment: If the app has been transferred in App Store Connect then the bundle ID won't change. If it did, it would be a new app and existing users wouldn't get any upgrades.